# How can i make media Query work in IE7 and IE8

Tags: css, media-queries

Hi I am tring to make a responsive page using media Query and i want it to be worked in IE7 and IE8

Can anyone please help on this issue.

thanks in advance

Comment: According to http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp, these browsers have currently 4.6% on the "market".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet will probably be using a JS library. Respond.js (https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) is a great solution for media queries for IE8 and lower. One word of caution: its written pretty narrowly (only has support for `min-width` and `max-width` queries) but should have enough for the basics.